# Android файл расширений .obb

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-studio

Как создать такой файл, как с ним работать, например если мне нужно вытаскивать из него картинки для ImageView.

В этом вопросе новичок. Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На developer.android все подробно описано
http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/google/play/expansion-files.html

### 1. jobb tool

**запуск:**
jobb [-d ][-o ][-pn ][-pv ] \ [-k ][-ov][-dump ][-v][-about]
**создание *.OBB:**
$ jobb -d /temp/assets/ -o my-app-assets.obb -k secret-key -pn com.my.app.package -pv 11

### 2. Downloader Library

**Подключить Downloader Library в sdk загрузить:**
 - Google Play Licensing Library package
 - Google Play APK Expansion Library package

### 3. Обьявить userPermition

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

### 4. downloader service

```
public class SampleDownloaderService extends DownloaderService {
    public static final String BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY = "YourLVLKey";
    public static final byte[] SALT = new byte[] { 1, 42, -12, -1, 54, 98,
            -100, -12, 43, 2, -8, -4, 9, 5, -106, -107, -33, 45, -1, 84
    };

    @Override
    public String getPublicKey() {
        return BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getSALT() {
        return SALT;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAlarmReceiverClassName() {
        return SampleAlarmReceiver.class.getName();
    }
}
```

### 5. alarm receiver

```
public class SampleAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            DownloaderClientMarshaller.startDownloadServiceIfRequired(context,
                intent, SampleDownloaderService.class);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

### 6. Загрузка

```
boolean expansionFilesDelivered() {
    for (XAPKFile xf : xAPKS) {
        String fileName = Helpers.getExpansionAPKFileName(this, xf.mIsBase,
            xf.mFileVersion);
        if (!Helpers.doesFileExist(this, fileName, xf.mFileSize, false))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Check if expansion files are available before going any further
    if (!expansionFilesDelivered()) {
        // Build an Intent to start this activity from the Notification
        Intent notifierIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.getClass());
        notifierIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        ...
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notifierIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Start the download service (if required)
        int startResult =
            DownloaderClientMarshaller.startDownloadServiceIfRequired(this,
                        pendingIntent, SampleDownloaderService.class);
        // If download has started, initialize this activity to show
        // download progress
        if (startResult != DownloaderClientMarshaller.NO_DOWNLOAD_REQUIRED) {
            // This is where you do set up to display the download
            // progress (next step)
            ...
            return;
        } // If the download wasn't necessary, fall through to start the app
    }
    startApp(); // Expansion files are available, start the app
}
```

- Start the download service (if required)

```
int startResult =
    DownloaderClientMarshaller.startDownloadServiceIfRequired(this,
            pendingIntent, SampleDownloaderService.class);
if (startResult != DownloaderClientMarshaller.NO_DOWNLOAD_REQUIRED) {
    mDownloaderClientStub = DownloaderClientMarshaller.CreateStub(this,
            SampleDownloaderService.class);
    setContentView(R.layout.downloader_ui);
    return;
}
```

### 7. Using APKExpansionPolicy ...

Comment: Есть ли еще какие-то примеры?